# outlook 2013 add space between table

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, email

After digging and testing along many hour, i can't find howto solve this bug.

Has you can see, on the image, extra space appear on outlook 2013, and in a minor way on outlook 2007/2010.

the email source: http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/test.html

[image: exemple]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fmj5osk8/

```
        <table class="bodyTable" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="background-color:#ffffff; color:#000000;font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size: 14px;border-collapse:collapse;margin:auto;border-spacing: 0;" >
        <tr>
            <td  width="600" valign="top" style="line-height: 16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;vertical-align: top;">
                <table class="header"  width="600"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin:auto;border-spacing: 0;" >
                    <tr>
                        <td height="158" style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;height:158px;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            <img style="display: block" src="http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/img/header.jpg" alt="test" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  width="600" valign="top" style="line-height: 16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;vertical-align: top;">                
                <table  width="600" height="69" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin:auto;border-spacing: 0;">
                    <tr align="center" >
                        <td height="69" width="119" style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            <img style="display: block" src="http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/img/l_titre.jpg" />
                        </td>
                        <td height="69"  style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;" >
                            <h1 style="font-size: 20px;padding:0;margin:0;margin-top:0;margin-bottom: 5px;color:#E9E00B;" >
                                Dolor si amet
                            </h1>
                            <span style="font-style: italic;padding:0;margin:0;">
                                dolor si amet
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td height="69"  width="43"  style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            <img style="display: block" src="http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/img/r_titre.jpg" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  width="600" valign="top" style="line-height: 16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;vertical-align: top;">                
                <table  width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin:auto;border-spacing: 0;">
                    <tr align="center" >
                        <td  width="55" style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            <img style="display: block" src="http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/img/l_h_text.jpg" />
                        </td>

                        <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;" >

                            <p>
                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend mauris eget bibendum condimentum. Integer dapibus eu magna ac gravida. Donec volutpat auctor nisi in mattis. </p>
                            <h2 style="font-size: 16px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Lorem ipsum</h2>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend mauris eget bibendum condimentum. Integer dapibus eu magna ac gravida. Donec volutpat auctor nisi in mattis. </p>

                            <h2 style="font-size: 16px;margin-bottom: 5px;">Lorem ipsum</h2>
                            <p>
                           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend mauris eget bibendum condimentum. Integer dapibus eu magna ac gravida. Donec volutpat auctor nisi in mattis.  </p>
                            <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla eleifend mauris eget bibendum condimentum. Integer dapibus eu magna ac gravida. Donec volutpat auctor nisi in mattis.   </p>


                            <div style="margin:0px;padding:10px;border:3px solid yellow;border-radius:5px;text-align: center;">
                                <h3  style="font-size: 14px;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-top:5px;">Lorem ipsum:</h3>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor <br />
                                Lorem dolor si amet bibendum<br />
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td  width="55"  style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;" >

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  width="600" valign="top" style="line-height: 16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;vertical-align: top;">  
                <table  width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin:auto;border-spacing: 0;">
                    <tr align="center" >
                        <td height="62"  width="55" style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            <img style="display: block" src="http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/img/l_b_text.jpg" />
                        </td>

                        <td height="62" style="vertical-align: middle;overflow:hidden;" >
                            <h2  style="font-size: 16px;padding:0;margin:0;margin-bottom: 5px;">Dolor si amet</h2>
                        </td>

                        <td height="62"  width="55"  style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  width="600" valign="top" style="line-height: 16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;vertical-align: top;">                

                <table  width="600" height="110" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin:auto;border-spacing: 0;">
                    <tr align="center" >
                        <td  height="110" width="195" style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            <img style="display: block" src="http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/img/l_footer.jpg" />
                        </td>

                        <td height="110" style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;" >
                            <p style="font-size: 14px;margin:0px;">
                                Dolor si amet,<br />
                                <b style="line-height: 25px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">L’équipe de test</b><br />
                                <span>dolor si amet</span><br />
                                <span style="line-height: 25px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">07 25 54 54 54 </span><br />
                                <a href="http://www.test.fr" style="color:#000000;text-decoration:none;">www.test.fr</a><br />
                            </p>
                        </td>

                        <td height="110" width="206"  style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            <img style="display: block" src="http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/img/r_footer.jpg" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  width="600" valign="top" style="line-height: 16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;vertical-align: top;">                

                <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin:auto;border-spacing: 0;" >
                    <tr>
                        <td height="99" style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;height:99px;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" >
                            <img style="display: block" src="http://a-part.fr/mailing/test/img/b.jpg" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  width="600" valign="top" style="line-height: 16px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;vertical-align: top;">                

                <!-- désinscription mailjet -->
                <p style="text-align: center;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;">
                    <a href="[[UNSUB_LINK_FR]]">Se désabonner</a>
                </p>
                <!-- fin désinscription mailjet -->

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all of this extra nonsense on cells you don't need, especially the ones housing images :
style="vertical-align: top;overflow:hidden;line-height: 0; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"

That fixed it for me :)

Comment: This is what i made a the beginning, and i have added this extra nonsense to try to fix it after reading some articles.
In fact remove that will not fix the probleme

Comment: I've tested in Email on Acid and my own work Outlook 2013, before and after removing those styles and it's now fixed when removing them. Maybe try it and test again?

Comment: I have tried this on litmus. I will retry tomorrow, after a good night of sleep ...

Comment: Right ! it seems to be " vertical-align: top;" which was the cause of this bug, valign="top" is ok !
Thanks !

Comment: Good to hear you found a resolution :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that adding style="font-size:0%;" in TDs that only contain images resolve this.

So chats around that: https://litmus.com/community/code/538-vml-outlook-07-10-13-unwanted-20px-padding-at-the-bottom

Comment: There isn't any vml in this code though, which is what your link is referencing. Will it still help? I feel like there is something bigger going on here as this never happens to me and my first test is to my Outlook 2013

Comment: Yep - should work: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3795/outlook-2013-says-no-to-empty-table-cells